# How to exclude files or views from joomla debug?

Tags: joomla-3.x, joomla-framework-1.x

JLog is serializing everything in its way

```
$signature = md5(serialize($options));
```

https://github.com/joomla/joomla-cms/blob/ac589fd45aaa88a5e9d972cacceec083cb4c754b/libraries/joomla/log/log.php#L191

In our plugin we are reading xml file to get the template version tag
https://github.com/YJSGframework/yjsg/blob/master/includes/yjsgcore/classes/yjsg.class.php#L380

But with joomla debug on, that data gets serialized and I get an error .

```
 Serialization of 'SimpleXMLElement' is not allowed
```

If I try to unserialzie SimpleXMLElement data I get no data back .

Is there a way to exclude specific files or views from Jlog ?

**update:** 
Dmitry pushed me to check more and here is what I get

error everything on 
http://prntscr.com/5d51ip

changed signatrue var 
http://prntscr.com/5d51tx

no SimpleXMLElement error.
http://prntscr.com/5d51yg

or if I change serialize to json_decode

```
$signature = md5(json_decode($options));
```

everything works.

Comment: Are you sure that it's a JLog problem? It is serializing only `$options`, not everything.

Comment: testing all option as we speak but it does look like it

Comment: @DmitryRekun I traced it back from debug plugin line 147
http://prntscr.com/5d4zzp, when that line is removed everything is ok. Now it might not be the signature line but it is addLogger method

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure that this will solve your problem, but it does answer your question in that you referenced `libraries/joomla/log/log.php`.

Per [Using JLog](https://docs.joomla.org/Using_JLog), and the [JLog Class Reference](http://api.joomla.org/cms-3/classes/JLog.html), only the component, output file, priority, and format can be specified, but nothing else - no exclusions.

Also, this applies to adding a jLog to your code, unless you're intending to change core files and set options there.

*On a side note*, I've noticed that when I specify a file name for output, it seems to become the default file for Joomla once a log entry is made. I haven't had a chance to investigate it, and it hasn't interfered, but may be handy to know.

Comment: I Up you for the actual answer. but the solution is , remove xml data from class public var , the bug is still valid as I pointed out above

Comment: +1 for the question to begin with, and I didn't think it would actually solve the problem as I said :).  I just wanted to contribute something to anyone that might need an answer the question asked - bug or not :)